# iPhone 6: InteractionDiaog appears too far down; content hidden

Tags: codenameone

I am trying to implement a chat function in a Codename One app, basically using the tutorial example "[Building a Chat App with Codename One](http://www.codenameone.com/blog/building-a-chat-app-with-codename-one-part-1.html)". Part of this is an InteractionDialog popping up when someone is trying to contact you. This looks fine in the simulator and on my Android unit, but on iPhone 6 the dialog seems to be drawn too far down, resulting in only the title being visible.

This is the program code:

```
    int h = toast.getPreferredH();
    int dh = Display.getInstance().getDisplayHeight(); // just for debugging
    toast.show(Display.getInstance().getDisplayHeight() - h - 10, 10, 10, 10);
    UITimer uit = new UITimer(() -> {
        toast.dispose();
    });
```

Toast height, display height:
*Simulator*: h=221, dh=480
*Android*: h=359, dh=1674
*iPhone 6*: h=304, dh=1334 (This one comes too near the bottom)

Is there something wrong with the screen metrics, and what can I do to solve this? I have had some other, similar problems with InteractionDialog placement previously.

I would be happy to show some screenshots, but I can't post that many links yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the code for the chat app might have been a bit wrong here change this:

```
int h = toast.getPreferredH();
int dh = Display.getInstance().getDisplayHeight(); // just for debugging
toast.show(Display.getInstance().getDisplayHeight() - h - 10, 10, 10, 10);
```

To this:

```
int h = toast.getPreferredH();
int dh = Display.getCurrent().getContentPane().getHeight();
toast.show(dh - h - 10, 10, 10, 10);
```

The layered pane (where the [InteractionDialog](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/components/InteractionDialog.html) resides) is on top of the content pane area only not the entire display height so the title area/statusbar area aren't taken into account.

FYI in the upcoming version we will have the new [ToastBar component](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/components/ToastBar.html).

Comment: News about the ToastBar is great! Was planning implementing something similar for an app that I'm working on but I think I'll just wait for this. Any idea when it will be available? I have two questions about the API:

Comment: 1. Can ToastBars be cascaded? Use case: For example when network is down, I want to show a permanent 'offline mode' message. However, in the mean time, there might be 'real toasts' in which case I'd like to show second toast temporarily above the permanent 'offiline mode' notice. Is that possible?

Comment: 2. Can we add buttons to the toast bar? This is common e.g. in the gmail app where a right-aligned 'UNDO' button is added to the toast. Here's an example: http://i.stack.imgur.com/LWClq.jpg

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. Using the whole display height was a bit suspicious, but I didn't know what to replace it with. Looking forward to the ToastBar!

Comment: @Shai: I've posed my questions [here](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/toastbar-gaussian-blur.html) :)